# Transaction Scope - "The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction" error and has to restart DTC service every time

Tags: multithreading, windows-10, transactionscope, msdtc

I am getting "The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction" error while using Transaction Scope with Multi-threading using Dependent Transaction. If I restart the DTC service then its works fine for first time but getting this error from second time onward. This behavior I seen on Windows 10 but it completely works fine on Windows Server 2016 OS.

I am using following configuration of DTC and using SQL Server and Application on same box so no Firewall Issue in the scope.

[image: DTC Properties]

Comment: allow remote clients without any auth?

Comment: pls post the offending code. You might have 2 connections to the same DB inside a Transaction scope, or a nested transaction.

Comment: also, I notice you don't accept many answers.....

Comment: I am referring sample code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/managing-concurrency-with-dependenttransaction

Comment: @MitchWheat - I am using separate DBContext object for each thread.